# How to send Azure devops Service hooks event metadata to jenkins pipeline as parameter

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline

want to send some Service hook event metadata infomrationto jenkins pipeline, such as commitid, author username and email.

We have created Service hook from Azure devOps to Jenkins. Build is getting triggered successfully whenever any code changed, also choosed accept parameter option in service hook. Now wanted to send send event data details as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> How to send Azure devops Service hooks event metadata to jenkins pipeline as parameter

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid we could not send Azure devops Service hooks event metadata to jenkins pipeline as parameter. Because the Build parameters only supports hard coding for now. So we could not send those dynamically parameters `commitid`, `author username` and `email`.

As workaround, you can create a CI build in Azure Devops which is trigged when pushing changes to repository and add a [Jenkins Queue Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/jenkins-queue-job?view=azure-devops) task in the build to trigger the Jenkins Job. With this build task, you could pass the branch name dynamically by using the predefined variables:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unable to pass paramters. When i run job, i am getting below error while queuing the job.

Job creation failed.
HttpResponse.statusCode=400
HttpResponse.statusMessage=Bad Request
##[section]Finishing: JenkinsQueueJob

Comment: parameters i passed as below.

source=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)
agent=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)

Comment: @krishnabh, According to the error message, it seems more related to the connection issue. You can verify it without parameters and click the "Verify connection" link to verify it.

Comment: I already verified, without parameters its working fine. When passing parameters, i am facing the above issue.